# Hyperlink with hashtag do not open in new tab

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, hashtag

i am using this code to open all the URLs in new tab.
but i want the url with # do not open in new tab. for example:

```js
jQuery("a").attr("target", "_blank");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">content</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `href` attribute value before appending `_blank`.

```
jQuery("a").attr("target", function() {
  if ($(this).attr('href') != '#') {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
  }
});
```

In the above code, we check for the `href` value, if it's `#` then ignore it, else append `_blank` value to the elements target.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Luj79hqq/3/)

---

If you are looking to ignore all `a` tags where `href` starts from `#`, you can do something like

```
jQuery("a").attr("target", function() {
  if ($(this).attr('href')[0] != '#') { //checks for the first char, if #, ignore
    return '_blank';
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Luj79hqq/5/)

Comment: Also checked #contact?

Comment: @vusan Aah, I thought he wants to ignore blank hash urls, will modify

Comment: @Mr.Alien the second demo is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks

Comment: Yea, I thought you wanted to ignore the ones with `#` only.. @SajjadAhmad

Answer (score 0):

You can check working fiddle [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/t0fkzL5p/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/t0fkzL5p/)

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr("href");
  if(href!="" && href!="#"){
    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
});
```